# docker-compose syncing file content changes on host to volume mounted on docker container

Tags: python, docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, cron-task

I have a script that uploads the file to S3 bucket every minute using crontab. I'm uisng docker to run the script, I need the changes made to the file on the host to be reflected on the docker container and uploaded to S3 bucket.

The script uploads `/data/boo.txt` to S3 every minute.

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_bucket_name = 'ap-rewenables-feature-data'

with open("/data/boo.txt", "rb") as f: 
    s3.upload_fileobj(f, s3_bucket_name, "boo.txt")
```

My `Dockerfile` install `boto3` library using pip, sets aws credentials and uses `crond` to run the script at scheduled intervals.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

WORKDIR /scripts

RUN pip install boto3

ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=#########
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=##########

COPY s3-file-upload-crontab /etc/crontabs/root
RUN chmod 644 /etc/crontabs/root

COPY s3_operations.py /scripts/s3_operations.py
RUN chmod +x /scripts/s3_operations.py

ENTRYPOINT crond -f
```

```
*/1 * * * * python /scripts/s3_operations.py
```

From what I know I have to use `bind mount` to keep the directory synced between the host and the container. I'm using `docker-compose.yml` to define the service and `bind mount`.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  data-transfer:
    image: ap-aws-s3-file-upload 
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

Running `docker-compose up` creates the container, the script runs every minute and uploads the file. But I have trouble syncing the file contents between host and container. No matter what changes I make to `boo.txt` the file in the S3 bucket doesn't reflect them.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, shouldn't `bind mount` keep track of file contents?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use the host's cron daemon; don't bother with Docker here.  (Also look at your image's `docker history`, and decide whether you've compromised your AWS credentials and need to rotate them.)

Comment: @DavidMaze normally I would, but as this needs to be delpoyed on multiple machines, and the rest of the project is already optimized for docker I'm trying to keep it consistent. As for the credentials, it's new account, not sure how much could've happened over a day.

Comment: Are you sure you make changes to the right file? Your compose file has relative mount path, which is evaluated according to the directory from which you run `docker-compose up`.

Comment: @EY yes, I'm running `docker-compose up` from the same folder as where the `docker-compose.yml` is located, would I even be able to run it outside the project? That folder has a `data` directory with `boo.txt` which is the file I'm trying to keep is sync. Even is I switch the host path from `./data` to full path `/home/$USER/git-projects/ap_renewables/aws-s3-poc/data` nothign changes.

Comment: Have you tried doing docker exec into your container and checking if the changes are reflected there?

Comment: @Carlos yes, the change I make on the host is reflected in the container.

Comment: Then I would say it's something with the upload script.  Are you able to exec into the container and run the script manually to see if it uploads the updated file?

Comment: I've checked the S3 bucket and the file is uploaded every minute, the date changes, so that seems fine.

Comment: I understand, but it's not getting the updated file, correct?  I'm suggesting you run the script manually inside the container to see if it uploads the updated file.  Something else to try would be to update the file from within the container and see if those updates are uploaded.

Comment: I've fixed it somehow. I've run `docker image rm -f image_id` to remove the old image and rebuild the entire thing from ground up using `docker-compose up --build --detach`.  Now the changes made on host are reflected in both the container and in file uploaded to the S3.

Comment: If someone can explain that bizare behaviour I'll be grateful. Maybe something to do with cache?